# GD: php imagepng creates whitespace in image

Tags: php, png, gd

I have some problem with GD when i creates images with php.

The strange thing is that it works on one server with php version 5.3.1 but not on php version 5.2.14. (I'm not sure if it's the php version or the GD lib that is doing this.)

[image]
This file is created with convert and saved in a directory in `captcha::get_file()`.

[image]
And this file is generated with `imagecreatefrompng()` and `imagepng()`

[image]
I made some small changes to the script and made a gif. But there is still a problem with the png

What causes this, and how can I fix it?

Here is the phpcode:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("./captcha.php"));    

// creates the image with convert and returns the location of the picture
// document_root/picture/picture.png
$picloc = captcha::get_file(); 

$image = @imagecreatefrompng($picloc); 

header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($image);

imagedestroy($image);

unlink($picloc);
?>
```

Comment: Odd, never seen anything like this before. You will need to show some of the captcha code I think...  What happens if you omit the `content-length`? What happens if you use some other format like gif?

Comment: I tried the content length, but nothing changed. I will try the gif, but it won't fix the problem.

Comment: What about this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php#90364 (using true colors)

Answer (score 0):

not positive, but the problem may be in your content length header.

```
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($image));
```

at this point in your code, $image is a resource data type, not a string. try simply removing the content-length header line, and see what happens.

Comment: the above remains true. strlen is used for figuring out the length of a string, and $image is not a string.